# Should we close questions we find the answer to before someone else does?

Tags: discussion, questions

A few moments I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194270/how-to-properly-design-a-linearlayout-with-textviews-on-each-side/27194303#27194303).

Almost immediately, as I was reviewing my question for spellcheck errors, I spotted the solution. I answered my own question, so that others wouldn't waste their time looking into it.

Should we leave questions like this on the site, as it could still potentially help others who face the same problem, or should I delete/vote to close this because I asked a question about something I really didn't end up struggling with?

Comment: What should be wrong with posting an answer yourself, if you think your question is valid regarding the SO policies, and maybe useful for future research?

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for that! Voted to close.

Comment: It's the first time I see a question voted to close by its own OP... nice

Comment: @Patrice This site has done a lot to help me, I do what I can to maintain its high quality. Even if that means admitting and correcting my own mistakes.